# Putting the data in the designated date in highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I am currently making a monthly chart using highcharts and I want to output the data in its designated date, What should I do? Im just learning how to use highcharts using dynamic data.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"projects");

    /* Getting purchases table data */
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(total_cost) as count FROM purchases
            GROUP BY MONTH(`date`) ORDER BY `date`";
    $purchases = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $purchases = mysqli_fetch_all($purchases,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $purchases = json_encode(array_column($purchases, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);


    /* Getting sales table data */
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(product_total) as count FROM confirm_order_product
            GROUP BY MONTH(`date`) ORDER BY `date`";
    $sales = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $sales = mysqli_fetch_all($sales,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $sales = json_encode(array_column($sales, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);



?>
<script type="text/javascript">

/*series: [{
        name: 'Sales',
          data: data_sales,
         // pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 1, 1),
         //  pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000

      },{
         name: 'Purchases',
        data: data_purchases
     //   pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 1, 1),
     //    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
   }]*/

$(function () {


    var data_sales = <?php echo $sales; ?>;
    var data_purchases = <?php echo $purchases; ?>;


    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Sales and Purchases'
        },
        xAxis: {
            //categories: ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','Sepmtember','October','November','December']
            type: 'datetime',
           dateTimeLabelFormats: {


      month: '%b ',

           },
           title: {
               text: 'Date'
           }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales',
            data: data_sales

        }, {
            name: 'Purchases',
            data: data_purchases
        }]
    });
});
```

I have data in the month of Sep,Nov,Dec and none for the rest and when I run the code it displays Jan,Feb & Marc instead of the real date.

Comment: Could you share `data_sales` please ?

Comment: @Core972 what do you mean by that?

Comment: Please edit the question to add the content of `data_sales`.

Comment: Perhaps your data is badly structured and that's why Highcharts render something different than you expect. As @Core972 mentioned please show your `data_sales` and `data_purchases` content or prepare a simplified online example with hardcoded data (jsfiddle, codepen).

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: @Core972. Is that it?

Comment: You've added the SQL query. Please add data that is the response from a database. Data that you providing to Highcharts as `data_sales` and `data_purchases`.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel The values that the `data_sales` and `data_purchases` only gets the `total_cost` and `product_total` from the database and its not getting the `date`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data **doesn't contain dates** you have to specify it in chart options. The first approach is to use `datetime` axis and set appropriate pointStart and pointInterval:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 8, 1),
      pointInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o4cq132m/

The second approach is to use categories like that:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['Sepmtember','October','November','December'],
    title: {
      text: 'Date'
    }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h9ykq7mf/3/

When your data **contain dates** you can provide them like that:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1535752800000, 122], // [timestamp in milliseconds, value]
      [1538344800000, 131],
      [1541026800000, 111],
      [1543618800000, 120]
    ]
  }]
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zhynkgoa/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: My data got dates, how can I include that?

Comment: I updated my answer. I encourage you to check Highcharts api where you can find all these informations: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data